# finding value of indefinite integration of $\frac{y^7-y^5+y^3-y}{y^{10}+1}dy$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

finding value of indefinite integration  $\displaystyle \int\frac{y^7-y^5+y^3-y}{y^{10}+1}dy$

$\displaystyle \int\frac{y^5(y^2-1)+y(y^2-1)}{y^{10}+1}dy = \int\frac{(y^5+y)(y^2-1)}{y^{10}+1}dy = \int\frac{(y^5+y)(y^2+1-2)}{y^{10}+1}dy$

$\displaystyle =\int\frac{y^5+y}{y^8-y^6+y^4-y^2+1}-2\int\frac{y^5+y}{y^{10}+1}dy$

i wan,t be able to proceed after that, could some help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:   We can write our integral as, $$I = \int \frac{y^7-y^5+y^3-y}{y^{10}+1} dy = \int \frac{y(y^6-y^4 + y^2-1)}{y^{10}+1} dy = \int \frac{y(y^6-y^4+y^2-1)}{(y^2+1)(y^8-y^6+y^4-y^2+1)} dy$$ We can use partial fractions and get $$I = \frac{1}{5}\int \frac{4y^7-3y^5 +2y^3-y}{y^8-y^6+y^4-y^2+1} dy -\frac{4}{5} \int \frac{y}{y^2+1} dy =I_1-I_2$$ I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: I hope that you noticed that you answered came out 23 minutes ago and that, 9 minutes ago, was edited an answer which, initially, did not provide almost anything. In any manner, $+1$ for your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: put $u = y^2$, and note that $(y^5 + y)dy = y(y^4+1)dy = \dfrac{u^2+1}{2}du$. Would this enable you to continue?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$y^{10}+1= \left( {y}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {y}^{8}-{y}^{6}+{y}^{4}-{y}^{2}+1
 \right) 
$$
further we get
$$\frac{y^7-y^5+y^3-y}{y^{10}+1}=1/5\,{\frac {y \left( 4\,{y}^{6}-3\,{y}^{4}+2\,{y}^{2}-1 \right) }{{y}
^{8}-{y}^{6}+{y}^{4}-{y}^{2}+1}}-4/5\,{\frac {y}{{y}^{2}+1}}
$$

Comment: Can you please write other steps?

Comment: It is done by Rohan